# Array Loop with FirebaseObservable

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm Working on the following Component:

```
import {BudgetItem} from "../models/budget.model";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {FirebaseListObservable, AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable} from "angularfire2";

@Injectable()
export class BudgetService{

  public ausgaben:number;
  public einnahmen:number;
  public budgetArray = [];

  private budget:FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  private budgetItemToUpdate;

  constructor(private af:AngularFire){
    this.budget = af.database.list('/Budget');
    this.ausgaben = this.getAusgaben();
    this.einnahmen = this.getEinnahmen();

    this.budget.subscribe(items => {
      // items is an array
      items.forEach(item => {
          this.budgetArray.push(new BudgetItem(item.zweck,item.betrag,item.ausgabe));
      });
    });
  }

  //Nimmt ein BugetItem als Parameter und fügt dieses der Datenbank als neuen Datensatz bei
  addToBuget(item:BudgetItem){
    this.budget.push({zweck:item.zweck,betrag:item.betrag,ausgabe:item.ausgabe});
  }

  //Nimmt den Key eines Objekts und löscht das jewelige Objekt aus der Datenbank
  removeFromInventar(key:string){
    this.budget.remove(key);
  }

  //Synchronisiert ein bestehendes Objekt mit der Datenbank
  updateBudgetItem(item){
    this.budgetItemToUpdate = this.af.database.object("Budget/" + item.$key)
    this.budgetItemToUpdate.update({zweck:item.zweck,betrag:item.betrag,ausgabe:item.ausgabe});
  }

  //berechnet die totalen Einnahmen. Als Anfangswert wird 2500(Budget) gesetzt.
  getEinnahmen(){

    this.einnahmen = 2500;

    console.log(this.budgetArray);

    for(let item of this.budgetArray){
      if(item.ausgabe === "Einnahme"){
        this.einnahmen = this.einnahmen + item.betrag;
      }
    }
    console.log(this.einnahmen);
    return this.einnahmen;
  }




  //berechnet die totalen Ausgaben. Als Anfangswert wird 0 gesetzt.
  getAusgaben(){

    this.ausgaben = 0;

    console.log(this.budgetArray);

    for(let item of (this.budgetArray)){
      if(item.ausgabe === "Ausgabe"){
        this.ausgaben = this.ausgaben + item.betrag;
      }
    }

    console.log("Ausgaben: " + this.ausgaben)
    return this.ausgaben;
  }

}
```

I can suggestfully push my items in the array, but I want to add up the itempropertiy "Betrag" of the idividual Objects and display the sum of them.

Where is my Mistake or what kind of suggestions do you have to get the code working?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. *Conceptually* you have an async list of objects with a `betrag` property and you want to add up all `betrag` properties?

Comment: that's correct, but I have a problem with the Implentation of the add-up part.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gist of it:

```ts
af.database.list('/Budget')
  // Reduce all the items to a single value.
  .map(items => items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.betrag, 0))
  // Log the total
  .do(total => console.log(total));
```

Hopefully you can adapt this code to your situation. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getEinnahmen(){

    this.einnahmen = 0

   this.af.database.list("/Budget",{query:{
     orderByChild:'ausgabe',
     equalTo:'Einnahme'
   }}).map(items => items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.betrag, 0))
   // Log the total
     .subscribe(total => {console.log(total);this.einnahmen = total;});

   return this.einnahmen+2500;

  }
```

I changed up the code with the reduce-method. Now I'm able to log the total to the console, but now i want to add it as the returnvalue of the method getEinnahmen.